# How to get template name inside template

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to get template name while inside template?
Example:

```
<xsl:template name="list">
<!-- Get name value (in this case "list") -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are seeking this kind of functionality? Perhaps there is an alternative approach.

Comment: I would like to add wraper div, and give it class with same name. Then i want to add css styles, and for every css rule insert .list class before rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, neither XSLT 1.0 nor XSLT 2.0 offer such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin says, there's probably no way to do this.

Even if such a capacity existed, surely using it couldn't be any simpler than just defining a variable with the value you want:

```
<xsl:template name="list">
   <xsl:variable name="class" select="'list'" />
```

and then using that variable where you need it.  This also has the benefit that you can change the template name without rewriting all your CSS, or change the class name without rewriting your XSLT.

Comment: Well atleast now i know that it is impossible... TY :) btw i decided to pass parametr when i call template, and then i just copy/paste same name as template name and parametr value...

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of the fact that XSLT uses XML syntax is that it's easy to transform stylesheets. Modifying every named template to contain a variable holding the template name is dead easy.

Answer (score 1):

@JLRishe's answer is a good approach. However, there is a trap. Any `<xsl:param>` must be declared **before** any `<xsl:variable>`.

This will not work:

```
<xsl:template name="foobarsnafu">
    <xsl:variable name="foo" value="bar">
    <xsl:param name="snafu"/>
```

But this will:

```
<xsl:template name="foobarsnafu">
    <xsl:param name="snafu"/>
    <xsl:variable name="foo" value="bar">
```

This might be a problem if, for example, you want the default value of your `snafu` `<xsl:param>` to be the value of your `foo` `<xsl:variable>`. The way around it would be to use `<xsl:param>` with a default value for your template name, i.e.:

```
<xsl:template name="foobarsnafu">
    <xsl:param name="template_name" select="foobarsnafu"/>
```

Comment: I think you'd want `select="'foobarsnafu'"` so you're not trying to select an element named "foobarsnafu".